# Trying to run selenium chromedriver headless?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-headless

So I'm trying to scrape some forecasting data from a website periodically, and ideally I would like for it to happen in the background. I had a look at some documentation and came up with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.windguru.cz/53')
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#forecasts-page")))

\#Scraping block of code goes here

driver.quit()
```

I think the following line is over-riding the --headless argument but i'm not sure.

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#forecasts-page")))

The reason I have it added in the first place is that the website I'm scraping isn't just static html (have a look for yourself, link is in code). I think there's some js that prompts the forecast data to load, so I need to wait a bit and make sure before the script starts scraping the dom.

Any idea how I can achieve this and run the browser in headless mode?

Comment: Duplicate driver is what's causing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The line that's opening the chrome is this

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

You can do away with this and code should still work the same.

Comment: Thanks fo the reply however I still can't get it to work. I removed the bit of code you suggested however it's still not running headless. I then realised i have a similar looking line above:    

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)     

I tried removing that as well however then my code blows up. Any suggestions?